# How to use PUT instruction using curl in Canvas rest api

Tags: perl, api, rest, curl, put

I have the following code to get the data drom Canvas REST API this data contains information like start date of course and end date of the coursse.I have to change end_date of this course .I use GET to to get the information as shown in Program :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';

my $auth = "xxx";
my $curl = "curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer $auth'";

#system("curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer $auth'https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses");
#system("curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer $auth' https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/accounts/$accountid/analytics/current/grades");


system("$curl https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10300000000000133");

    my $json = '["golden", "fleece"]';
    my $perl = parse_json ($json);
```

The output of program is:

```
{"id":10300000000000133,"name":"DOV DEV","account_id":10300000000000001,"start_at":"2014-07-01T13:31:00Z","grading_standard_id":null,"is_public":true,"course_code":"DOV DEV","default_view":"feed","enrollment_term_id":10300000000000001,"end_at":"2016-05-28T04:00:00Z","public_syllabus":false,"storage_quota_mb":15000,"is_public_to_auth_users":false,"hide_final_grades":false,"apply_assignment_group_weights":false,"calendar":{"ics":"https://canvas.instructure.com/feeds/calendars/course_Jo1suCoQU3XhYMBJNm3Ziu2POTG4GL6DjzHJ7PM4.ics"},"sis_course_id":null,"integration_id":null,"enrollments":[{"type":"teacher","role":"TeacherEnrollment","role_id":822,"user_id":10300000000020171,"enrollment_state":"active"}],"workflow_state":"available","restrict_enrollments_to_course_dates":false}host-155-246-165-53:~ ajinkyabobade$
```

After getting the information as shown above I am using the -X PUT command to change the end_date .The code including PUT is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';

my $auth = "xxx";
#my $accountid = "10300000000000133";
my $curl = "curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer $auth'";
#system("curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer $auth'   https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses");
#system("curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer $auth' https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/accounts/$accountid/analytics/current/grades");


system("$curl https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10300000000000133 -X PUT -d 'end_at=2017-05-28T04:00:00Z' ");

my $json = '["golden", "fleece"]';
my $perl = parse_json ($json);
```

The end_date is not changing using this code also I am getting the following output, Please help

```
{"id":10300000000000133,"name":"DOV DEV","account_id":10300000000000001,"start_at":"2014-07-01T13:31:00Z","grading_standard_id":null,"is_public":true,"course_code":"DOV DEV","default_view":"feed","enrollment_term_id":10300000000000001,"end_at":"2016-05-28T04:00:00Z","public_syllabus":false,"storage_quota_mb":15000,"is_public_to_auth_users":false,"hide_final_grades":false,"apply_assignment_group_weights":false,"calendar":{"ics":"https://canvas.instructure.com/feeds/calendars/course_Jo1suCoQU3XhYMBJNm3Ziu2POTG4GL6DjzHJ7PM4.ics"},"sis_course_id":null,"integration_id":null,"workflow_state":"available","restrict_enrollments_to_course_dates":false}host-155-246-165-53:~ ajinkyabobade$
```

Comment: It would be better to use `LWP` instead if shelling out to curl. And it is hard to tell what may be wrong as the correct code depends on the instructure.com API

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
```

`use warnings` shows more problems than plain `use strict`; Always good to use them together.

```
use JSON::Parse 'parse_json';
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper; # just for output

my $url = 'https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/10300000000000133';
my $auth = 'xxx';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
```

see http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent for the manual.

Add the auth header to all upcoming requests once:

```
$ua->default_headers->header('Authorization' => "Bearer $auth");
```

Create a sub calling your API. This sub could merge everything common to all API requests and add error handling:

```
sub api {
    my ($method, $args) = @_;
```

`@_` holds the arguments passed when calling the sub. `$method` will get the first argument: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` or any other valid HTTP method, `$args` should contain the arguments to send.

Create a request object:

```
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new($method, $url);
    $req->content($args)
        if $args;
```

Run the request, actually call the API:

```
    my $result = $ua->request($req);
```

Parse the result and return a Perl data structure if the request was successful (HTTP status code 200):

```
    return parse_json($result->decoded_content)
        if $result->is_success;
```

Otherwise report errors. Using [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) might be better depending on your script:

```
    print "Error calling $method with ".
        ($req->content // 'no body').":\n".
        $result->as_string;
}
```

Issue a GET request without any arguments and show the Perl structure returned:

```
print Dumper(api('GET'));
```

Issue a PUT request with arguments:

```
print Dumper(
    api('PUT' => 'end_at=2017-05-28T04:00:00Z');
);
```

This script has few differences compared to your CURL approach above:

- It does error handling
- It doesn't depend on external tools

In case your REST API replies with a HTTP status code 500 or 404, your script would just ignore that and treat the request as successful. This script would dump the full HTTP response. You might want to act on different HTTP codes by reading `$result->code`.

If you don't get an error, but still nothing happens: Try to comment the `return parse_json(...) if $result->success` out to see the full HTTP response. Maybe you get a hint from a header value or see something in the body.

The [Canvas API documentation](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/index.html) states:

> POST and PUT requests may also optionally be sent in JSON format
>   format.

You might want to switch to the [JSON module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) which could do `from_json` and `to_json` at the same time.

I didn't find any information about their error handing in the API documentation. If in doubt, try generating an error (like using an invalid ID or querying a GET API with invalid arguments) to get an idea on how their errors look like.

Try another write (PUT) action to see if your problem is related to your sample.

Comment: Thank you,will you please elaborate on line: " my ($method, $args) = @_;" .Will you please tell what is the method and what is the argument you are trying to pass in your code .

Comment: Added a comment to the answer. `$method` is the HTTP method and `$args` are the arguments (if any).